# Very strange Objective C error

Tags: objective-c

I'd say I know Objective C pretty well. But I've just tracked down a bug to something very strange.
I have an "int mode;" member variable in a class. And just writing "mode;" in the init method changes the behavior of the class (it doesn't get dealloced later on)
Even though the compiler gives me the warning "Statement has no effect"

What is going on ?
Can I not be sure of when an object is dealloced ?

Here's my code in a bit more detail:

```
@interface HelpScene : CCScene {
    int mode;
}
```

and in the implementation

```
- (id) init {
    if (self=[super init]) {
        [[SomeObject alloc] initWithBlock:^(id sender) {
            mode;  // CHANGES BEHAVIOUR
            [Call CCDirector.replaceScene which usually ends up deallocing self
            (the current scene). But not with the previous line anymore]
        }
    }
    return self;
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The reference to `mode` is shorthand for `self->mode`, which induces the block to retain the class instance.

Comment: With blocks, garbage collection, multiple ways to call methods (self.running and [self running]) Objective - C is getting complicated. Too complicated. At some point, when the system becomes complicated enough, we spend our brain power on the syntax of the language, and not creating.

Comment: Spot on ! thanks. I didn't know blocks could be tricky like that. I replaced it with a selector mechanism and it works fine now.

Comment: Sorry - forgot to point out in my comment that Marcelo's solution is succinct and correct.

Comment: But still, the compiler warning "Statement has no effect" is wrong.

Comment: @vlad2048: The warning is correct in the sense that the statement itself doesn't do anything, and will almost certainly be elided by the optimiser. It is misleading, of course, because the mere existence of the statement causes another piece of (hidden) code to behave differently.